# inner joins with where clause for no values?

Tags: mysql, join

I have 2 tables :

Table1

```
Parent(varchar) Child (varchar)
```

Table2

```
C1(varchar)    PC (varchar)
```

Sample data:

[image]

Requirement - I need Table2.C1 values for which column Table2.PC = Table1.Child , but Child values must be different from Table1.Parent's values..

I'm using below query in mysql:

```sql
select distinct(C1),Child,PC 
  from Table2 inner join Table1 
    on Table2.PC=Table1.Child 
 where Table1.Child not in (select Parent from Table1);
```

It is giving empty set, but there are values in Child which is same as in PC, but not in Parent....

Where I'm getting wrong?

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and desired output to illustrate your question?

Comment: yeah .. i provided same

Comment: And what is the desired output based on this sample data?

Comment: i need those C1 values...where Pc's value is EQUALS to child, but these EQUALS values should not be value of PARENT , ...

in above attached pic , i should get C1 value where Child = 'qwer'; so qwer is not present in Parent , but is in PC and Child

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
SELECT DISTINCT t2.c1, t2.pc, t1.child
  FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN table1 t3
    ON t1.child = t3.parent JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.child = t2.PC
 WHERE t3.parent IS NULL
```

Output:

```
|   C1 |   PC | CHILD |
|------|------|-------|
| mono | qwer |  qwer |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/14785/7)** demo

Comment: ok..its nice..but if m running below query :
select distinct child from T1 where child not in ( select Parent from T1);

this is giving more count ...and in your query it is is giving more...as far as i concerned this count should be same...

Comment: @user21546 You get more rows with your query because you have `child` values in `table1` that are not in `PC` column in `table2`. And they are filtered out when `INNER JOIN` is used with join with table2. Now what I didn't get is whether the proposed query answered your question?

Comment: i have no values in Child that is not present in PC..I have every Value in PC that can or cannot be present in Parent

Answer (score 0):

The "where" clause excludes everything in Table1

Provide sample data in the question if you would like an SQL query example

Comment: why where clause excludes EVERYTHING...it will exclude only PARENT PART...

Comment: the statement (select parent from table1) returns all parent records, so no Table1.Child cells can match any parent cells.

Comment: sir , thats why i have mentioned where child not in ( select Parent from t1)

Answer (score 0):

Runing your query with the shown data gives me 1 result with 
C1 = mono, 
Child = qwer and 
PC = qwer

The data you display should provide that result, according to the query.

If you do not get the same result, my guess is that you have **more** data in your tables than you show here which is filtering away the result; or there's some other factor you're not mentioning.